# Heroku app crashing whenever I try to open it

Tags: ruby, heroku

From Heroku, when I click "Open App," I am taken to a screen that shows the message below:

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>
> ```
> heroku logs --tail
> ```

When I run this command in my terminal, I get the following:

```
2023-05-02T20:55:46.008048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-brushlands-01940.herokuapp.com request_id=089a1f69-2776-42f8-96fe-6483816d7db6 fwd="76.100.146.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-05-02T20:55:46.296015+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-brushlands-01940.herokuapp.com request_id=7eedd68b-4683-4ab5-ae47-35f00fb6b958 fwd="76.100.146.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's a more detailed look at the stack trace:

```
2023-05-02T21:46:58.098960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-brushlands-01940.herokuapp.com request_id=a0d2bfa4-b583-4cd4-91d8-aa4524886c18 fwd="76.100.146.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-05-02T21:46:58.380588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-brushlands-01940.herokuapp.com request_id=4badb527-3741-4426-9bee-c6ca4d8fd3f2 fwd="76.100.146.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-05-02T21:47:14.133483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-05-02T21:47:22.910963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2023-05-02T21:47:25.776952+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2023-05-02T21:47:25.776974+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.1.4.6 application starting in production
2023-05-02T21:47:25.776974+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2023-05-02T21:47:25.777930+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778017+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:17:in `dirname': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778020+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:17:in `realpath'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778023+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:7:in `block in initialize'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778023+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:11:in `call'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778024+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `require_relative'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778028+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778030+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778032+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778032+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778033+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778033+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778033+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778035+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778036+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778044+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778044+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778051+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778052+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778059+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778059+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778060+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778076+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778076+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778077+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778077+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2023-05-02T21:47:25.778079+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2023-05-02T21:47:26.022304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-05-02T21:47:26.060411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-05-02T21:47:26.064963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-05-02T21:47:34.265381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2023-05-02T21:47:35.951605+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2023-05-02T21:47:35.951635+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.1.4.6 application starting in production
2023-05-02T21:47:35.951635+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952460+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952519+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:17:in `dirname': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952522+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:17:in `realpath'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952524+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:7:in `block in initialize'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:11:in `call'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `require_relative'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952528+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952530+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952532+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952534+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952534+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952535+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952543+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952543+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952543+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952544+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952544+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952545+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952553+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952553+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952554+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952554+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952555+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952556+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952563+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952563+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952565+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952565+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952566+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952567+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2023-05-02T21:47:35.952567+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2023-05-02T21:47:36.141842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-05-02T21:47:36.218370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, but it suggests I should be up and running with the app without issue.  I have been unable to figure out why my app is crashing.

I have tried the `heroku restart` command multiple times, and I've added `x86_64-linux` as a PLATFORM in my Gemfile.lock. I have no idea what the issue is or how to further troubleshoot it.

I tried other suggestions I found on Stack Overflow, but none of them resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you do what the error message said? That should give some clues at least. Without a [mre] there's not much anyone can do for you.

Comment: How does the full error message including the stack trace look like?

Comment: @spickermann added as a snippet above

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this--I am not 100% certain what fixed it.  I swapped my Gemfile for the more up-to-date one on [Hartl's Github page](https://github.com/learnenough/rails_tutorial_7th_edition_gemfiles/blob/master/hello_app/Gemfile_final), updated my version of Ruby to match his (3.1.2) ran `bundle update`, pushed the updated Gemfile.lock to Git and Heroku, and now the Heroku app works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try update gem irb. I have the same issue while upgrading ruby from 3.0.6 to 3.1.4 and irb was 1.6.4. Upgrading irb from 1.6.4 to 1.8.1 fixes:

```
`bootsnap/load_path_cache/realpath_cache.rb:17:in `dirname': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`
```

Maybe it is related with custom irb history file.